# Unity timer count down not working when app killed android

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to unity and c#, I have a code to increase energy after 10m, I have used PlayerPrefs to do so it is working in unity but not working on mobile please help.
I'm unable to understand what exactly is causing problem in phone. Also the timer pauses when the app is not killed but just minimized on mobile. I want the timer countdown to keep going game minimized and also if killed.

```c#
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class EnergyAdder : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public float waitTime = 600;
    Timer timer;
    public GameRoot gameRoot;
    public int count;
    DateTime currentDate;
    DateTime oldDate;

    void Start()
    {
        //timer = new Timer(waitTime);
        float remainingTime = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("TimeOnExit");
        timer = new Timer(remainingTime);
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("sysString"))
        {
            currentDate = DateTime.Now;
            long temp = Convert.ToInt64(PlayerPrefs.GetString("sysString"));
            oldDate = DateTime.FromBinary(temp);
            TimeSpan difference = currentDate.Subtract(oldDate);
            count = (int)(difference.TotalSeconds / waitTime);
            Debug.Log("time remaining " + count);
            gameRoot.AddEnergy(count);
            timer = new Timer(remainingTime - (float)difference.TotalSeconds);
            //PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("TimeOnExit");
            //PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("sysString");
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Gameroot.isFull)
        {
            GetComponent<Text>().text = "Full";
            count = 0;
            timer.refresh();
        }
        else
        {
            //Debug.Log("deltatime ************************"+ secondstime);
            timer.countDown();
            if (timer.isFinished())
            {
                timer = new Timer(waitTime);
                timer.refresh();
                gameRoot.AddEnergy(1);
            }
            UpdateClock();
        }
    }

    void UpdateClock()
    {
        int seconds = ((int)timer.timeLeft) % 60;
        int minutes = (int)(timer.timeLeft / 60);
        GetComponent<Text>().text = minutes.ToString() + ":" + seconds.ToString("00");
    }

    void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("TimeOnExit", timer.timeLeft);
        var today = DateTime.Now;
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("sysString", today.ToBinary().ToString());
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
}
```

Please help what is wrong in above code or what is missing.

Comment: I think for the minimizing you should use [`OnApplicationPause`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationPause.html) and maybe also [`OnApplicationFocus`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationFocus.html)

Comment: I want to handle both app minimized and kill. So help me with something that works for both.

Comment: Can't you just do the same thing as you do in `OnApplicationQuit` also in `OnApplicationPause(true)` and `OnApplicationFocus(false)` and the same you do in `Start` in `OnApplicationPause(false)` and `OnApplicationFocus(true)` ?

Comment: I'm new to unity, can you please explain like what is `true` and `false` indicate or what exactly you are trying to explain.

Comment: I tried to do in my answer below. I can't test if this solves it but you could try. With `true` and `false` I refer to the value passed to the methods in short: `OnApplicationPause` takes a `bool pasueStatus` which is `true` if paused, otherwise `false`. `OnApplicationFocus` gets a `bool hasFocus` which is `true` if the app has the focus, otherwise `false`. Checkout the two linked APIs for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`OnApplicationQuit`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationQuit.html)

> Note: iOS applications are usually suspended and do not quit. You should tick "Exit on Suspend" in Player settings for iOS builds to cause the game to quit and not suspend, otherwise you may not see this call. If "Exit on Suspend" is not ticked then you will see calls to `OnApplicationPause` instead.

I suspect it is just the same with modern Android where your app is also not really closed but hibernate.

So I think you could use [`OnApplicationPause`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationPause.html) and [`OnApplicationFocus`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationFocus.html)

> On Android, when the on-screen keyboard is enabled, it causes a `OnApplicationFocus(false)` event. Additionally, if you press "Home" at the moment the keyboard is enabled, the `OnApplicationFocus()` event is not called, but `OnApplicationPause()` is called instead.

and just do the same as you do in `OnApplicationQuit` also for `OnApplicationPause(true)` and `OnApplicationFocus(false)`

and do the same as you do in `Start` also in `OnApplicationPause(false)` and `OnApplictionFocus(true)` like

```c#
public class EnergyAdder : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float waitTime = 600;
    public GameRoot gameRoot;
    public int count;

    // already reference this in the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private Text timerText;

    private Timer timer;
    private DateTime currentDate;
    private DateTime oldDate;

    private void Awake()
    {
        // store this reference ONCE
        if(!timerText) timerText = GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        GetTime();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // Note: probably a typo? shouldn't it be "gameRoot" ?
        if (Gameroot.isFull)
        {
            timerText.text = "Full";
            count = 0;
            timer.refresh();
        }
        else
        {
            //Debug.Log("deltatime ************************"+ secondstime);
            timer.countDown();
            if (timer.isFinished())
            {
                timer = new Timer(waitTime);
                timer.refresh();
                gameRoot.AddEnergy(1);
            }
            UpdateClock();
        }
    }

    private void UpdateClock()
    {
        int seconds = ((int)timer.timeLeft) % 60;
        int minutes = (int)(timer.timeLeft / 60);
        timerText.text = $"{minutes}:{seconds:00}";
    }

    private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        StoreTime();
    }

    // pauseStatus is True if the application is paused, else False.
    private void OnApplicationPause(bool pauseStatus)
    {
        if(pauseStatus)
        {
            StoreTime();
        }
        else
        {
            GetTime();
        } 
    }

    // hasFocus is True if the GameObjects have focus, else False.
    private void OnApplicationFocus(bool hasFocus)
    {
        if(hasFocus)
        {
            GetTime();
        }
        else
        {
            StoreTime();
        }
    }

    private void StoreTime()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("TimeOnExit", timer.timeLeft);
        var today = DateTime.Now;
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("sysString", today.ToBinary().ToString());
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }

    private void GetTime()
    {
        // NOTE: You should consider to pass a default value like
        //float remainingTime = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("TimeOnExit", 15);
        float remainingTime = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("TimeOnExit");
        timer = new Timer(remainingTime);
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("sysString"))
        {
            currentDate = DateTime.Now;
            long temp = Convert.ToInt64(PlayerPrefs.GetString("sysString"));
            oldDate = DateTime.FromBinary(temp);
            TimeSpan difference = currentDate.Subtract(oldDate);
            count = (int)(difference.TotalSeconds / waitTime);
            Debug.Log("time remaining " + count);
            gameRoot.AddEnergy(count);
            timer = new Timer(remainingTime - (float)difference.TotalSeconds);
        }
    }
}
```

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone so I can't test it but I hope it goes into the right direction*

Comment: Amazing, this code has solved my other issue that I was getting while application quit. Thank you so much man. You are always there to help for unity.

Comment: Updated code `timer = new Timer((double)remainingTime - difference.TotalSeconds);` this is giving error ` Argument 1: cannot convert from 'double' to 'float'`.

Comment: Wait isn't that the .Net [`Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Timers_Timer__ctor_System_Double_)? It should take a `double` not a `float` .. or are you using a different `Timer` implementation?

Comment: I'm just using unity `Timer` in `c#`.  I new to unity and also new to `c#`,  just learning both of them.

Comment: If it says `using System.Timers;` on top of your file you are using that one ... I'm just confused because the constructor takes a `double` ^^

Comment: Noted so I will convert them to `float`. Do you do freelancing for unity, I know this is not allowed to be asked over here, but I need guy for my project.

Comment: yeah, I think your `Timer` is a custom class because the .NET `Timer` also has no `timeLeft` property ;) so just stick to `float` then, sorry for the confusion. And no, sorry ;) I am working a lot with Unity professionally